# How to insert a conditional combobox?

Tags: vba, combobox

I'm working with VBA, and I'm struggling to get a combobox with two options:

- First option: the textbox next to it must appear one "-", like if is supposed to be empty or disabled.
- Second option: the same texbox must must be able to receive an input, like numbers.

Like: "Do you have an ID?" if no, don't fill the texbox. If yes, fill it with your number.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include more details of what your system is using (JQuery? Angular? Winforms?) as well as specific parts of the problem you are having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm really new in this..
I'm using VBA, and the problem is in the combobox: If I chose one option, I want this option to make other texbox unable to receive any imput. If i chose the other option, I want the same texbox to be able to receive an imput, like a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming C# implementation but this would work essentially for any .net or WINFORMS project.

```
if(cbo.selectedindex = 0)
   tbFoo.text = "-";
else if(cbo.selectedindex == 1)
   tbFoo.text = "filltextwithID";
```

Check if the selectedindex of your combobox is the first or second options in the list and do your first option with the first selectedindex, else if it is the second, fill your textbox with whatever you need to fill it with(textwise).

Use your **conditional** if statement(naturally, I know) to check your conditions that you want your combobox to do to your textbox.

Otherwise another way to do this is with a `selectedindexchanged` event and do your switch statement or if statement based on which selectedindex you are talking about. `0` is the first item....all the way up to `n` items.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Im using VBA, but I guess the code is really similar to this one you wrote.. Do you think it will work if I put in VBA as:

`Private Sub ComboBox_Change()

if(cbo.selectedindex = 0)
   tbFoo.text = "-";

else if(cbo.selectedindex == 1)
   tbFoo.text = "filltextwithID";

End Sub`

Or somethig like that?

Comment: Yes. That sounds about right. I don't use vba unfortunately anymore, but that sounds right.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer. Either mine or yours.

Comment: Didn't know about that, will mark as soon it's avaible for me to do it! Tks!

Comment: When I tried, I got a message that I couldn't check the answer today.. anyway, it's done now, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Here's the code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Change()

    If ComboBox = "I don't have an ID" Then
    IdTextBox.Visible = False     'Hidden
    IdLabel.Visible = False

    Else
    IdTextBox.Visible = True    'Unhidden
    IdLabel.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```